# Verify the following rate question?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can someone help point out where I went wrong?

Question:

Sand is being poured from a conveyor belt at the rate of 100 cubic feet per
minute. The sand form a pile that is the shape of a cone whose base diameter always
equals the height. At a particular time, the height of the cone is increasing at 4 feet
per minute. How high is the sandpile at that time?

My answer: 5.641

Answer key answer: 2.8209

My solution: Since radius is half of the height I made the equation for volume $$V =\frac{pi}{3}(\frac{h}{2})^2h$$

Then I found the derivative. $$100 =\frac{pi}{3}(\frac{3h^2}{4}dh)$$

Then after inputting the rate the height is changing (4).  $$100 =\frac{pi}{3}({3h^2})$$

And finally solving for h, which is where I got 5.641. Where did I go wrong?